# Automatically ignore empty rows for diagrams in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc

The task I am trying to get done is the following (hope I am able to clarify what I mean):

1. LibreOffice 5.0.5.2
2. 1024 rows of data in a Calc sheet
3. ~256 lines with excerpts of the data right of the original
4. these excerpts are shown (or not shown) based on a flag in the same row
5. these flags are set by conditions I want to change several times to plot several different scenarios
6. every time the flags change, another subset of the 1024 rows will have data in them at the right side
7. this data shall be plotted in a bar chart
8. I do not want to select ~256 by hand, but instead I want to select the whole block on the right and tell LibreOffice *use only the rows with data in it to plot and ignore the rest*

   (Ideally I would tell this only one time, then change the flags and the diagram would get updated with the now filled rows)

Any suggestions what I might have overseen and how to accomplish this task?

Comment: 1) What type of chart are you using?  2) Have you tried simply defining the entire potential range as the data range?  I just did a quick test and it ignored missing data.

Comment: 1.) bar chart with % would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with a bar chart is that it treats every entry as a category, regardless of the content.  So empty cells have a location in the chart:

[image: all data]

Add a filter on the data, and deselect empty cells (or choose Not Empty):

[image: menu]

Only cells with values will be included:

[image: no empty cells]

Comment: thx, looks like what I searched for, much bett than my current Pivot table try